# Date time picker - validate date

Tags: javascript, datetimepicker

I am having an issue trying to validate a manually entered date with the date time picker.

I have seen similar questions where the solution was to make the field read only so they need to use the calendar.  That is not an option because we want to allow the user to manually enter the date.

My issue seems to be with `validateOnBlur`.  If I set it to true it automatically changes the value to the current time, I want to leave what they keyed in and show an error message.  The issue there is that if `validateOnBlur` is set to `false` it doesn't execute the `onChangeDateTime` block, so I cannot validate the value.

It only seems to be an issue with an invalid format.  If I enter `06/09/2015 11:77` it executes the `onChangeDateTime` block and my invalid date message is displayed.  However, if I enter `06/09/2015 1177` it either changes the value to the current time (`validateOnBlur=true`) or doesn't execute the `onChangeDateTime` code (`validateOnBlur=false`).

Am I missing something?  Is there another option I need to set?  Any suggestions to correct this?

Here is the block where I create the `datetimepicker`:

```
form.find("#effectiveFromDate").datetimepicker({
    format:"m/d/Y H:i",
    formatDate:"m/d/Y",
    formatTime: "H:i",
    timepicker: true,
    validateOnBlur: true,
    step:5,
    minDate: minDate,
    maxDate: maxDate,
    onChangeDateTime: function(ev){
        validateFromToDates(form, minDate, maxDate);
    }
})
```

Comment: easiest solution is to chain `.prop('readonly',true)` on to the end, then the user has to use the ui and cannot enter date manually

Comment: As I said in the post, that is not really an option as we want to allow the user to enter the date with the keyboard if they choose.

Comment: The docs do not mention that `validateOnBlur` is required to be true before `onChangeDateTime` will be called.  Several examples omit `validateOnBlur` all together and they seem to work.  Are you sure this is the case?  Have you tried debugging to make sure your `onChangeDateTime` is not being called?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer.
Yes, I have tried debugging.  The onChangeDateTime is always executed if validateOnBlur is true.  If it is false it will execute if the value is a valid date, but will not execute if the date is not valid.
If you look into jquery.datetimepicker.js there are 2 instances of validateOnBlur, 1 where it sets the default (true) and an if statement where it sets up the logic.  This logic is where it sets the value to the current date if the date is not valid.  After changing the date it triggers changedatetime.xdsoft.

Comment: I added an else statement to the validateOnBlur our copy of the date picker to still trigger the onChangeDate without changing the field value.  That seems to work.